# javascript method sort: end of task

Tags: javascript, sorting, methods

I'm sorting a big array in JavaScript via the method array.sort(),

While calling sort() I'd like to display a loader gif, in order to show that the script is running.

then I'd like to hide this loader and throw a function: when the task is finished

How can we know whent the new array is available with sort() method ?

```
// This will sort by Year
function sortByYear(a, b){

    var aYear = parseFloat(a.year)
    var bYear = parseFloat(b.year)

    if (aYear < bYear) {
      return 1;
    } else if (aYear > bYear) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: FYI, gif animation is stopped while executing JS functions.

Comment: I think the sort() method is synchroneous. Just show the loader, sort, and hide the loader and it should work. Oh, and Teemu is right, the viewport is frozen during a JS execution.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this: [**How to keep animated GIF running while doing intense calculations**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300632/how-to-keep-animated-gif-running-while-doing-intense-calculations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is a syncronous method, so the array is available when the method returns.

You could do that:

```
$("#loadingGIF").show();

var sortedArray = sourceArray.sort(...);

$("#loadingGIF").hide();
```

But that wouldn't work because the browser won't refresh the screen until the method finishes. You should do something like that:

```
$("#loadingGIF").show();

// wait a few milliseconds, just enought to the browser process next requests,
// like drawing the screen
setTimeout(executeSort, 100); 


function executeSort()
{
    var sortedArray = sourceArray.sort(...);

    $("#loadingGIF").hide();
}
```