# GIF animation stop during loop

Tags: javascript, loops, gif

I have a function in JavaScript which takes a long time to perform a calculation. I also have a GIF which I display before starting the calculation, just like a progress bar.

The issue I'm facing is that even though I set the GIF to show() it doesn't show up until the loop ends.

Here is the complete code:

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#progress').show();

        while(true){
            
            //calculation
        } 
    })
```

```html
 <div id="progress" style="display:none">
            <img alt="Loading .." src="UILayer/Images/ajax.gif" />
        </div>
```

The GIF starts animation after the loop is completed.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you are missing [`jquery`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiGkZjh-I_UAhXBMY8KHdlhA0oQFggrMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjquery.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFnz7C6MAXGLm7pVcOD_LrOjJUUiA&sig2=lCdYSEt9LCw-X5zKscagig) library link

Comment: Did you try some other gif to test?

Comment: what is your while condition?

Comment: @prasad no jquery is added in my page

Comment: @margarita Same behaviour with all GIF files

Comment: @Dinesh I have made slight change to the code, now there are no calculation inside while loop but it will run infinite time. even that does not work

Comment: I think you might want to check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300632/how-to-keep-animated-gif-running-while-doing-intense-calculations

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your gif is not working because it is slowed down by the js code that is running.

You can reproduce it by trying to put some alerts in the while loop.

Here is a related question:
[How to keep animated gif running while doing intense calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300632/how-to-keep-animated-gif-running-while-doing-intense-calculations)

Comment: Putting the alert in might help while you're developing to reassure yourself that you've reached the place in the program that you expected, but it would quickly become irritating for a normal user to respond to every alert in a long loop.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found setTimeout worked reasonably well:

```
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        //here I call the function or run the loop that
        //that uses a lot of processing power.
    }, 100);
```

It's not perfect. The progress animation doesn't run smoothly, but at least it appears before the longer action starts.